# Lodash: Group and restructure the json object

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

How can I group and restructure the JSON object using lodash. I have a JSON object like this:

```json
[
  {
    "time":"2021-03-30T09:00:29.000Z",
    "ngay":"2021-03-30",
    "status":0
  },
  {
    "time":"2021-03-30T09:00:38.000Z",
    "ngay":"2021-03-30",
    "status":1
  }
]
```

I want to group it like this:

```json
{
  "2021-03-30": [
    {
      "time":"2021-03-30T09:00:29.000Z",
      "ngay":"2021-03-30",
      "status":0
    },
    {
      "time":"2021-03-30T09:00:38.000Z",
      "ngay":"2021-03-30",
      "status":1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Nhân Lê. Please check the answer and mark the question as answered if it so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```
const list = [
  {
    "time":"2021-03-30T09:00:29.000Z",
    "ngay":"2021-03-30",
    "status":0
  },
  {
    "time":"2021-03-30T09:00:38.000Z",
    "ngay":"2021-03-30",
    "status":1
  }
]

const gropedList = _.groupBy(list, 'ngay')
```

For more information please check the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) documentation